# Array Results in 2 Columns Even When Odd

Tags: php

I am trying to return my array into two columns. It is working when the number of results is even, but not odd. When the results are odd, it keeps all of the results in the left `ul` but not the right `ul`.

How can I change the code so that if there is a remainder, it will put the odd number of results into the second column?

```
<?php 
$terms = get_field('featured_cities');
echo '<ul>';
$i =0;
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'cities').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
  $i++;
  if((int)sizeof($terms)/2 == $i){
     echo '</ul><ul>';
  }
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Hey Mark. It certainly does, but I'm wondering how to change the code so that if there is a remainder (when divided by 2), it gets handled differently.

Comment: This should probably be done [using CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) instead of hacking the HTML.

Comment: You use [`floor`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) to round fractions down, and the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to determine if there's a remainder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if (ceil(count($terms)/2) == $i){
```

instead of

```
if((int)sizeof($terms)/2 == $i){
```

Also, consider putting `ceil(sizeof($terms)/2)` in some  variable, so

```
<?php 
$terms = get_field('featured_cities');
echo '<ul>';
$i =0;
$half = ceil(count($terms) / 2);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'cities').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
  $i++;
  if ($half == $i){
     echo '</ul><ul>';
  }
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

If you want odd number in the second column, add fixing of `$half`:

```
$cnt = count($terms);
$half = ceil($cnt / 2);
if ($cnt % 2 && $half % 2) $half--;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because if the size of `$terms` is odd you are missing the opening `<ul>` tag.